# Android population ListView

Tags: android, listview

Nothing is displayed on my ListView from my database. Here's my code.

This is from Database Connections where data is gathered.

```
public Cursor getData(String hlth_cond) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String StringQuery = "";

    if(hlth_cond == "Highblood"){
        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME";
    }
    else if (hlth_cond == "Arthritis"){
        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME_Arth";
    }
    else if (hlth_cond == "Diabetic"){
        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME_Dia";
    }
    Cursor res;
    return res = db.rawQuery(StringQuery,null);

}
```

And this code is from my main activity

```
public void showList(){
    String toPass="";

    if(Cb_Ar.isChecked()){
        toPass = Cb_Ar.toString();
    }else if (Cb_Db.isChecked()){
        toPass = Cb_Db.toString();
    }else if (Cb_Hb.isChecked()){
        toPass = Cb_Hb.toString();
    }

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getData(toPass);
    String[] fromDb = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.RECIPE_NAME};
    int[] toView = new int[] {R.id.textViewMenuSuggest};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursor;
    myCursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.menushow,cursor,fromDb,toView,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursor);
}
```

Comment: Add some Log lines in your if else, also add an else at the end. Are you sure your hlth_cond matches any of these conditions?

Comment: What log lines should I ? Yes sir they matches, because I also tried removing the conditions still nothing appears on my ListView

Comment: are you sure your cursor have data ?

Comment: how can I know that I fetches data ? I try to view my Database via SQLite Manager plugins in Mozilla, pulling it out from my virtual device.

Comment: you need `_id` column in your `Cursor` for `CursorAdapter` to work, read  `CursorAdapter`'s docs

Comment: I should take the ID column too ?

Comment: and verify you have any rows in the `Cursor`, call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: what is your R.layout.menushow, SimpleCursorAdapter expects only a single TextView for display, maybe try using android.R.layout.simple_list_item and see if this works

Comment: it errors out the R.layout.simple_list_item "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: menushow layouts has an element of textview.

Comment: @inner_class7 with `SCA` you can have multiple Views, (not only TextViews)

Comment: it can have multiple views, since your only using one i was suggesting for testing to see if that works

Comment: @pskink what could be wrong with my code ?

Comment: Maybe SCA is not fetching any data on database ? or maybe im just wrong on how data must be passed ?

Comment: did you call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` ?

Comment: Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

is this what you are saying ?

Comment: i am saying `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: I dont know that sir. Im just new in android

Comment: just call [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor))

Comment: DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor); like this ?

Comment: anyways, where is it printing the cursor data fetched ?

Comment: did you read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor))?

Comment: Yes and I dont get it. :(

Comment: I feel like my cursor is not fetching any data from the database. 

        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME"; 
Is my query right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Menu to cook: "
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:text="@string/app_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/selectView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```